# How to save a field in the AspNetUsers table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have added a new field to the AspNetUsers table for the MVC application using EntityFramework code first model. I can access the field in one of my controllers by doing:

```
 var currentUser = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
 bool isPrivateModeOn = currentUser.IsPrivateMode;
```

How do I actually set a value (true/false) back to the field in the database? can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UpdateAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.updateasync?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager%601.UpdateAsync);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.2) for update user properties.

Comment: Vitally, awesome. Thank you.